# Долгое выполнение метода в новом потоке

Tags: c#, асинхронность, tpl, потоки-данных, методы

Есть метод

```
private void Generate(int xMax, int yMax, int categoryCount, int elementCount) {
    elementList = generator.GenerateSample(
        new Interval(0, xMax), new Interval(0, yMax), categoryCount, elementCount
        );
    ElementsGenerated();
}
```

При его обычном выполнении:

```
Generate(xMax, yMax, categoryCount, elementCount);
```

, программа выполняется ~8,9770973 с

При использовании:

```
await Task.Factory.StartNew(() => Generate(xMax, yMax, categoryCount, elementCount));
```

время выполнения выходит целых ~42,6324051 с

Мне нужен именно второй способ, ибо обновляется прогресс бар и выводятся информационные надписи на лейбл, а в первом случае видно только изменение прогресс бара, надписи не меняются, да и плюс ко всему окно неактивно.

Comment: Странно, такого быть не должно. Попробуйте попрофилировать выполнение: замерьте при помощи `StopWatch` каждый из кусков в синхронном и асинхронном режимах.

А как вы обновляете прогрессбар и лэйбл? Приведите больше кода, например, релевантную часть процедуры, вызывающей `await`.

Comment: Нашел интересную особенность своего кода. Дело в том, что задача у меня на данный момент - генерация элементов, генерирую я около 10kk элементов, и при каждом сгенерированном элементе у меня выкидывается событие. Видимо события - это и есть главная причина такого долгого выполнения. Немного поменял структуру программы, сделав не поэлементное выкидывание событий, а попроцентное, выполнение при 20kk элементах - 4-5 с

Comment: А, ну да, если у вас 10М синхронных вызовов в UI-поток, будет медленно. Перейдите на асинхронные вызовы (ну и конечно, 10М — это слишком много).

Comment: @MorkOFF48
если у вас ProgressBar имеет видимую длину 200 пикселей, а кол-во "обновлений" тысячу, то каждые 4 из 5 ничего не поменяют. Но вот у компонента ProgressBar есть странная особенность - он очень медленно обновляет себя.

В коде потока сделайте счетчик, который увеличивается каждый раз, когда бы Вы хотели послать сообщение и отправляйте их реже. 

было:

    sendMessageToMainThread(...);

будет

    count++;
    if (count % 100 == 0) {
      sendMessageToMainThread(...);
    }

вместо 100 лучше использовать число, которое равно кол-ву итераций разделенной на длину прогресса в пикселях

Comment: @KoVadim: Ну, негоже бизнес-логике знать такие подробности UI как ширина прогрессбара в пикселях. Концептуально правильное решение было бы выставить наружу `IObservable`, и пусть UI-код кластеризует его как хочет.

Comment: > бы выставить наружу `IObservable`

негоже бизнес логике на каждый чих дергать UI - это плохой дизайн. 

Я не писал, что нужно в бизнес логику передать ссылку на ui, где делать расчеты.

Мое предложение - у UI должен быть способ, с помощью которого она уведомляет бизнес логику, что бы выставить желаемую частоту присылки сообщений о изменении. например, 0 - не слать, 1 - слать очень редко. 10 - слать на каждый чих (для параноиков).

Comment: @KoVadim: А она (бизнес-логика) и не будет дёргать, если VM выдаст наружу `IObservable`. UI подпишется на него через [`Distinct(value / maxValue * pixelWidth)`](msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh211630.aspx), и тогда VM вообще не надо заботиться о наличии UI.